# Rails CORS and jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I have a little Rails based API. I'm trying to fetch data and show it in select via jQuery UI autocomplete. But there is an error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.exline.systems/regions/origin?title=%D0%95%D1%81. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

I have made all work with headers. For example, if I make direct request via browser:
http://api.exline.systems/public/v1/regions/origin.json?title=%D0%B0%D0%BB

I can see that all headers are served by server:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Request-Method:*
```

But using this code, headers are not served by server:

```
$(function() {
  $( '#calc-origin-ajax' ).autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
      $.ajax(
      {
        url: 'http://api.exline.systems/regions/origin',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { title: request.term },
        success: function (data) { response(data); }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you provide a link to

> http://api.exline.systems/public/v1/regions/origin.json

But trying to make request to

> http://api.exline.systems/regions/origin

With the first link all work fine: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vrbysj8n/3/)

Comment: Unfortunately, under localhost it's still not working. There are no such route  http://api.exline.systems/regions/origin.json. Only http://api.exline.systems/public/v1/regions/origin.json
Maybe I should fix smth in my browser to allow localhost requests?

Comment: if there is no such route, why are you trying to use it in your code?

Comment: I'm so sorry... Just have not slept for many hours. Was confused even when you showed mistake %)